# How to set thumbnails for youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to set thumbnails for my youtube video using javascript and tried the below but failed, so how do I fix it?

```
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId=MY_VIDEO_ID&uploadType=resumable", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer MY_KEY');

    ajax.onload = function () {
        if (ajax.status == 200) {
            console.log(response_body);
        }
    };
    ajax.send(file);
```

> { code: 401,   message: 'Invalid Credentials',   data:     [ { domain:
>   'global',
>          reason: 'authError',
>          message: 'Invalid Credentials',
>          locationType: 'header',
>          location: 'Authorization' } ] }

Comment: Add a link to the api docs that you are following. The Authorization header expects a token, not a key. Are you sending your API Key there, or are you using your key to get a token for use in this code?

Comment: i'm using Client ID because I can be upload video with this way, So I think it works, but not